# Missing resource instance key when using for_each in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am creating multiple s3 buckets using for_each in terraform. Here he the code I am using

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_private" {
  for_each = var.git_repo_branch_env
  bucket   = each.value.override_domain_name == "" ?  each.value.sitename_prefix == "" ? each.value.domain_name : join(".", [each.value.sitename_prefix, each.value.domain_name]) : each.value.sitename_prefix == ""  ? each.value.override_domain_name : join(".", [each.value.sitename_prefix, each.value.override_domain_name])
  force_destroy = true
}
```

I would like to set the ACL property for each of the buckets created, here is the code that I tried using

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "s3_private_acl" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3_private.bucket
  acl    = "private"
}
```

I get the following error message with that

> │ Error: Missing resource instance key │  │   on
> ../../modules/cloudfront-edge-auth-acp/main.tf line 149, in resource
> "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "s3_private_acl": │  149:   bucket =
> aws_s3_bucket.s3_private.bucket │  │ Because aws_s3_bucket.s3_private
> has "for_each" set, its attributes must be │ accessed on specific
> instances. │  │ For example, to correlate with indices of a referring
> resource, use: │     aws_s3_bucket.s3_private[each.key]

I get that the error message is because I have a for_each on my bucket resource and I need to add the ACL property for each of the buckets. But I am unsure of how to add the ACL property to each of the buckets.

Question: How do I assign the ACL property to each of the buckets created using for_each?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you created multiple buckets using `for_each`, same you need to do with ACLs:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "s3_private_acl" {
  for_each = aws_s3_bucket.s3_private
  bucket   = each.value.bucket
  acl      = "private"
}
```

It's well explained in Terraform documentation: [chaining for_each between resources](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each#chaining-for_each-between-resources).

Comment: That worked perfectly thanks. Am just getting started with Terraform and haven’t familiarised my self with the documentation yet.